# conduct Math operators on multiple aggregate functions SQL

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have 2 aggregate functions in my SQL query and I want to multiply one by the other, but when i try it gives me an error "not a GROUP BY expression". below is a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT S.employee, 
       avg(A.expected_duration) as duration1, 
       avg(A.efficiency) as efficiency1,
       duration1 *efficiency1 as product1

FROM S inner join A 
ON S.job_no = A.Job_no
GROUP BY s.employee
```

i've tried by putting an aggregate function before the math but it doesn't give the correct data. I'm at a loss here so any help would be appreciated. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So if you say.    - avg(A.expected_duration)*avg(A.efficiency) as product   - does that work?

Comment: yes that makes sense... thank you! it's always the simplest crap i get hung up on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refer to the alias of fields that you have called in the same select statement, you'll need to use the calculation rather than the alias

```
SELECT S.employee, 
       avg(A.expected_duration) as duration1, 
       avg(A.efficiency) as efficiency1,
       avg(A.expected_duration)*avg(A.efficiency) as product1

FROM S 
INNER JOIN A 
    ON S.job_no = A.Job_no
GROUP BY s.employee
```